# How to update application.properties file Value to another properties file Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 properties file application.properties and process.properties. I have to read spring.profiles.active from application.properties and need to call   process-{spring.profiles.active}.properties like process-dev.properties based on environment.

```
    <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:application.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:process-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

I am facing

> Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value
>   "classpath:process-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'spring.profiles.active' in value
>   "classpath:process-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"

Please Need Suggestion

Comment: You cannot. Property replacement is done once and not over and over until everything has been resolved. Also. you are using Spring Boot then why not use Spring Boot to do that (according to your tags that is).

Comment: I have to update process.properties file name from application.properties value based on spring.profiles.active value